# SpringBoot Mongo with unstructured documents

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a springboot app that is talking to a mongo database where one of the collections is somewhat "unstructured". The collection is all related to "app config" but different apps have different things in there. Some apps have just a few things at the top level, some have deep nested documents.

If there was some common "top level" document I'd have a class that just had like an `@Id String id`, and then a `Map<String, Object> info` or whatever but the "flexible" data is in the toplevel. So, can I just like extend MongoRepository with like `MongoRepository<Map<String,Object>, String>` or something? Is there a better way to handle stuff like this?

Comment: Use `MongoTemplate save()` method and pass the map wrapped inside  a `Document` with collection name as another argument. Something like `template.save(new Document(map), collection name);`

Comment: Use a relational DB?